# Decide placement and content of header for the references when using apa.cls

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

I'm using apa.cls in conjunction with biblatex. When printing the reference list, "REFERENCES" gets printed in the header, flushed to the left. However, I would like the text to be centered and to say something else. How would I go about fixing this?

Minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass[noapacite]{apa}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{A01,
  author = {Megalomanius, M.},
  year = {1900},
  title = {Why I am so great}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to customize the tile of the references section, you can use `\defbibheading`:

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\centering The New Name}
```

With the help og the [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package you can define a new page style (with customized headers and footers) to be applied to the references section:

```
\documentclass[noapacite]{apa}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\fancypagestyle{myrefstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{The New Header}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{A01,
  author = {Megalomanius, M.},
  year = {1900},
  title = {Why I am so great}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{myrefstyle}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the twoside option is in use, you'll have to replace

```
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

with

```
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

in my example code.

The `apa` document class uses upper case italics to format the headers, so you can use something like

```
\fancypagestyle{myrefstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\MakeUppercase{\itshape The New Header}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
}
```

to get the same style as the one used by `apa.cls`.

Comment: Thanks. This officially solves my question so I've marked it as accepted. However, when I compile everything I notice that the font of the text is a little bit thinner than the original header. Also, now, I've noticed that the original header isn't *exactly* centered. It alternates between being a little bit nudged to the right and a little bit nudged to the left. Can I extract the exact style from apa.cls somehow and use it within fancyhdr?

Comment: Notice that the thickness and size of the text gets right when I do nothing and just compile the file, getting the "REFERENCES" header.

Comment: @Speldosa: right now I have to leave, but as soon as I can I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Speldosa: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, the text still has some discrepancies between the two headers. For example, when I write "ARE" the R and E of the original header touches at the bottom. Not so with the new header. I'll just start a new thread to try to sort this out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Suppose I've defined a `pagestyle` (using `titlesec` package) called special. Is it possible to use it  within a `bibheading` defition by saying for instance:`\defbibheading{bibbook}[\bibname]{\chapter*{#1}\chaptermark{#1}\pagestyle{special}}` and then invoking with `\printbibheading[heading=bibbook]`?

Comment: @petobens perhaps you meant `\printbibliography[heading=bibbook]` instead of `\printbibheading[heading=bibbook]`? And regarding your question, yes, you could do that (just be careful that the mark you are declaring is the mark you will need for the declared page style).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes I meant `\printbibliography`. However I tried what you suggested and it is not working. Should I post a follow up question?

Comment: @petobens yes; seems the right thing to do. Don't forget to provide a MWE.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Here is my [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107081/9953)