# Getting the header for the references, using biblatex, to look *exactly* like the header for the main text, using apa.cls

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

*(This is a continuation of the question asked in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33391/decide-placement-and-content-of-header-for-the-references-when-using-apa-cls/33393#33393) thread)*

I'm using `apa.cls` (in doc-mode) in conjunction with `biblatex`. The `apa.cls` prints a header for me on every page, except for when `biblatex` prints the bibliography. At this point, is seems like `biblatex` takes over and creates a different heading which says "REFERENCES".

I would like to have *exactly* the same header for the references as for the rest of the paper. In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33391/decide-placement-and-content-of-header-for-the-references-when-using-apa-cls/33393#33393) thread (the same one which is linked to above), Gonzalo Medina suggested a solution using `\fancyhdr` and emulating the header of the `apa.cls`. However, this seems to run into all kinds of troubles. It is hard to get the *exact* fontsize, thickness of the text, placement et cetera correct. For example, `apa.cls` puts the header text in the middle but nudges it a couple of pixels back and forth depending on if it's written on an even or odd page (see [original thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33391/decide-placement-and-content-of-header-for-the-references-when-using-apa-cls/33393#33393) for more problems).

For consistency, I could just use `\fancyhdr` to redefine the header for the whole document but I'd like to use the header that `apa.cls` specifies (style-wise, it goes well with the main text). So, is there anyway for me to do this?

Minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass[noapacite, twoside, doc]{apa}

\title{This is the Title}
\author{Me}
\rightheader{this is the header}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{A01,
  author = {Megalomanius, M.},
  year = {1900},
  title = {Why I am so great}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\maketitle
\newpage
This is the first page.
\newpage
This is the second page.
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This generates the following output (the positioning nudge isn't obvious in these screenshot since they're not lined up):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say

```
\defbibheading{apa}[\refname]{\section*{#1}}
```

after having loaded **biblatex** and then

```
\printbibliography[heading=apa]
```

The default heading used by **biblatex** calls `\section*{\refname}` *and* `\markright{\refname}`. So the trick of defining a new header is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Speldosa I've added a bit of explanation (I was in a hurry when answering).

Comment: What a great answer. I exactly needed this. egreg I love you.