# Use pagestyle within bibheading definition in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

The following MWE prints a cumulative bibliography, subdivided by chapter, using `biblatex`. I would like to use the pagestyle called `special` within the bibheading definition rather than invoking it explicitly at the end of my document. I would also like that once the bibliography is printed the 'main' pagestyle is reestablished. So, is it possible to use a pagestyle (defined with [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/)) within a bibheading definition in `biblatex`? And can that pagestyle scope be limited to just the bibliography?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[pagestyles,outermarks]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}[\scshape]{%
  \headrule
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle]
  {\ifthesection{\thesection\space\,\sectiontitle}   
    {\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter. \chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
}
\newpagestyle{special}[\scshape]{%
  \headrule
  \sethead
  [\thepage][][\chaptertitle]
  {\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{main}

\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,refsegment=chapter,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

% Bibliography at the end:
\defbibheading{bibbook}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \chaptermark{#1}%
}
\defbibheading{subbib}{%
  \section*{\refname\addspace\chaptername\addspace%
  \ref{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}}
  \sectionmark{\refname\addspace\chaptername\addspace\therefsegment}
  % \thispagestyle{plain}
  % \pagestyle{special} % I WANT TO PLACE IT HERE
}

\addbibresource{bar.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\lipsum
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\nocite{*}

\chapter{Second}
\nocite{*}

\printbibheading[heading=bibbook]
\pagestyle{special}  % I DON"T WANT TO PLACE IT HERE
\bibbysegment[heading=subbib]

 \end{document}
```

Where `bar.bib` is

```
@Book{Jac08,
 author={M. O. Jackson},
 title={Social and Economic Networks},
 publisher={Princeton University Press},
 edition={2},
 address={Princeton, NJ}, 
 year={2008}}

@InBook{NeuNas54,
 author={Von Neumann, John and John Nash},
 title={Game Theory},
 booktitle={Microeconomic Theory},
 bookauthor={Andreu Mas Collel},
 publisher={Mit Press},
 address={Cambridge},
 year={1954}}

@InCollection{Sha53,
 author={Lloyd Shapley},
 title={A value for n-person games},
 booktitle={Contributions to the Theory of Games},
 editor={Harold Kuhn and Albert Tucker},
 volume={2},
 translator={Jurgen Pollock},
 origlanguage={german},
 publisher={Princeton Press},
 address={Princeton, NJ},
 year={1953}}

@Book{Dur05,
 author={Rick Durret},
 title={Probability Theory},
 edition={3},
 publisher={Duxburry Press},
 address={Belmont, Ca},
 year={2005}}

@InCollection{Tho95,
 author={Walter Thomson},
 title={Cooperative models of bargaining},
 booktitle={Handbook of Game Theory},
 volume={2},
 editor={Robert Aumman and I. Hart},
 publisher={North Holland},
 address={Amsterdam},
 year={1995}}

@Report{Car10,
 author={Xavier Carvalho},
 title={The Great Diversification},
 type={Working Paper 1624},
 institution={National Bureau of Economic Research},
 year={2010}}

@InCollection{LopInd83,
 author    = {Juan Lopez and Ignacio Indigo},
 title     = {Checking whether smartand work},
 booktitle = {Stack Exchange answers},
 editor    = {Domingo Peron},
 publisher = {Latex},
 address   = {Knuth Place},
 year      = {1983}
}
```

Comment: What about using `\preto{\bibbysegment}{\pagestyle{special}}`?

Comment: @Guido That is perfect for the bibliography segment, but I also want to restablish the `main` style afterwards. I tried using `\appto{\bibbysegment}{\pagestyle{main}}` but that obviously didn't work. Any idea on how to restablish the `main` style for subsequent pages?

Comment: I did some tests and, for some reason, the settings I suggested in my answer don't work in your MWE; unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to automatically restore the page style after the bibliography, so I am deleting my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for the attempted solution. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Would `\preto{\chapter}{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{main}` be an acceptable solution for restoring the `main` style after the bibliography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code whereby the new hook `\AfterRefsegments` is defined:

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd\AfterRefsegments[1]{\def\@AfterRefsegments{#1}}
\def\blx@bibbysegment[#1]{%
  \def\blx@theheading{bibliography}%
  \def\blx@theenv{bibliography}%
  \let\blx@theprenote\@empty
  \let\blx@thepostnote\@empty
  \let\blx@thetitle\@empty
  \c@refsegment\@ne
  \blx@safe@actives
  \setkeys{blx@bbg}{#1}%
  \blx@rest@actives
  \togglefalse{blx@tempa}%
  \blx@refsegments\@AfterRefsegments}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\preto{\bibbysegment}{\pagestyle{special}}
\AfterRefsegments{\clearpage\pagestyle{main}}
```